# How to make a two level colored box with text?

Tags: color, boxes, tcolorbox

I need some help to create boxes with two layers, color and text (as in the picture) that fit into textline. I thought about using `tcolorbox` but didn't work out for me yet. It is "needed" (it is not necessary but fancy ;) ) for working with the PCP-Algorithm (Theoretical computer science).

Hope someone has any good ideas.

[image: boxes i would like to have.]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. Nice BVB colours :-P `tcolorbox` should do very well

Answer (score 4):

The macro `\bibox{top}{bottom}` is what creates the box.  By default (`\biboxmode` = 0), the box width is set to the content width.  By resetting `\biboxmode` to something other than `0`, it will make all boxes of fixed width, using the parameter `\biboxwd`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine,xcolor}
\def\biboxmode{0}
\def\biboxwd{18pt}
\newcommand\bibox[3][\biboxmode]{%
  \setbox0=\hbox{\stackanchor{#2}{#3}}%
  \if0\biboxmode\else\wd0=\biboxwd\relax\fi%
  \setbox2=\hbox{\stackanchor[0pt]{\color{yellow}\colorbox{black}{\makebox[\wd0]{#2}}}%
  {\colorbox{yellow}{\makebox[\wd0]{#3}}}}%
  {\fboxsep=0pt\fbox{\box2}}%
}
\parskip 1ex
\begin{document}
: \bibox{bbaa}{ba}, \bibox{ab}{abb} und \bibox{ab}{aabb}\par
: \bibox{0}{00}, \bibox{001}{11} und \bibox{1000}{0}\par
Or else constant width:\def\biboxmode{1}\par
: \bibox{bbaa}{ba}, \bibox{ab}{abb} und \bibox{ab}{aabb}\par
: \bibox{0}{00}, \bibox{001}{11} und \bibox{1000}{0}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If one prefers the parameter `\biboxwd` to be not a "fixed", but rather a "minimum", box width (for `\biboxmode` other than `0`), then this code accomplishes that:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine,xcolor}
\def\biboxmode{0}
\def\biboxwd{22pt}
\newcommand\bibox[3][\biboxmode]{%
  \setbox0=\hbox{\stackanchor{#2}{#3}}%
  \if0\biboxmode\else\ifdim\wd0<\biboxwd\relax\wd0=\biboxwd\relax\fi\fi%
  \setbox2=\hbox{\stackanchor[0pt]{\color{yellow}\colorbox{black}{\makebox[\wd0]{#2}}}%
  {\colorbox{yellow}{\makebox[\wd0]{#3}}}}%
  {\fboxsep=0pt\fbox{\box2}}%
}
\parskip 1ex
\begin{document}
: \bibox{bbaa}{ba}, \bibox{ab}{abb} und \bibox{ab}{aabb}\par
: \bibox{0}{00}, \bibox{001}{11} und \bibox{1000}{0}\par
Or else apply minimum width:\def\biboxmode{1}\par
: \bibox{bbaa}{ba}, \bibox{ab}{abb} und \bibox{ab}{aabbbbb}\par
: \bibox{0}{00}, \bibox{001}{11} und \bibox{1000}{0}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Obligatory solution with Tikz!

### Output

[image: figure 1]

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.multipart}

\tikzset{
    split/.style={rectangle split, rectangle split parts=2, draw}
}

\newcommand{\double}[2]{%
\tikz[baseline=(a.center)]{
    \tikz \node[split, anchor=west, yshift=-1mm, minimum width=1cm, inner sep=3pt, rectangle split part fill={black,yellow}] (a) {\textcolor{yellow}{#1}\nodepart{two}#2};
}}

\begin{document}\noindent
:\double{bbaa}{ba}, \double{ab}{abb} und \double{ab}{aabb}\\
:\double{0}{00}, \double{001}{11} und \double{1000}{0}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @Dortmunder I see you're new, (welcome by the way), so remember to accept whichever answer solved your problem/you decided to adopt by clicking on the √ sign below the voting buttons. :)